# Find a group and three proper subgroups such that their union equals the original group.

Tags: group-theory, elementary-set-theory, finite-groups

Symbolically: Find a group $G$ with proper subgroups $H,K,L$ such that

$$G = H \cup K \cup L.$$

Since set unions don't respect group operations, it's hard for me to find subgroups that "close themselves" under the group operation when they're unionized. Any hints?

EDIT: Furthermore, how is this supposed to be feasible when [we have that unions of subgroups are not groups unless the constituent sets are comparable](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Union_of_two_subgroups_is_not_a_subgroup_unless_they_are_comparable)? (Perhaps I am reading the statement incorrectly?)

Comment: **Hint** : there's a similar exercise for vector spaces; if the field is infinite,  this cannot happen. What about if the field is finite ?

Comment: **Hint:** The group $G$ can't be cyclic, or one of the three subgroups would have to contain a generator. So you need a non-cyclic group. What's the smallest non-cyclic group you know of?

Comment: @bof The smallest non-cyclic group I know is the Klein-4 group, the symmetry group of a cross. Could I reasonably consider then a similar group $G = \langle a,b,c | a^2 = b^2 = c^2 = (ab)^2 = (bc)^2 = (ca)^2= 1\rangle$, and let $H,K,L$ be generated by $a,b,c$ respectively?

Also I have a followup I've edited into the question that's quite confusing to me, if you'd be so kind as to take a look.

Comment: I don't know why you're talking about a "similar group"; the Klein 4-group itself is the union of its three subgroups of order 2.

Comment: The page you linked to says that the union of ***TWO*** subgroups is not a group unless the subgroups are comparable. It doesn't say anything about the union of ***THREE*** subgroups.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Klein 4-group $V_4$ is the union of three proper subgroups. A group cannot be the union of two of its proper subgroups. It might be interesting to know, that research has been done on how this might generalize.

**Theorem** (Bruckheimer, Bryan and Muir) A group is the union of three proper subgroups if and only if it has a quotient isomorphic to $V_4$.

The proof appeared in the American Math. Monthly $77$, no. $1 (1970)$. The theorem seems to be proved earlier by the Italian mathematician Gaetano Scorza, *I gruppi che possono pensarsi come somma di tre loro sottogruppi*, Boll. Un. Mat. Ital. $5 (1926), 216-218$.

For 4, 5 or 6 subgroups a similar theorem is true and the Klein 4-group is for each of the cases replaced by some finite set of groups. For 7 subgroups however, it is not true: no group can be written as a union of 7 of its proper subgroups. This was proved by Tomkinson in 1997.

There is a nice overview paper by Mira Bhargava, *Groups as unions of subgroups*, The American Mathematical Monthly, $116$, no. $5, (2009)$.